# How to generate Native header files from java files in Android Studio

Tags: android, java-native-interface, header-files, javac

I am trying to learn Android Native programming , but i cannot use the Javac -h to generate header files from java source files .

`javac -h "destination path desired for header files" then i add Java source file`

BUT i keep getting errors saying : androidx... package does not exist .

after  searching i found that my $CLASSPATH is empty.
so i added -cp option and specified class path for android.jar , That resolved the android.os missing package .
But i cannot find the class path for jetpack package including androidx , i found that Gradle.build dependencies import the package from Maven repository .
So i really dont know what should i do . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

so i found out a solution , i dont know if its the typical solution or it should be done in another way ,
So basically i created a new java class containing only the native methods, without any other java methods / classes or imports .
then i use the Javac -h on that newly created class .
and it worked.Example:

```
public class native_methods_loader
{
  public native int nativeMethod();
}
```

then
`javac -h "jni folder path" ../native_methods_loader.java`

so this works and creates a header file named :
**com_programming_learn_native_methods_loader.h**
with a native method prototype called

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_programming_learn_native_1class_1loader_nativeMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jobject)
```